# Laravel Eloquent add a WHERE xy IS NULL condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I use Laravel 10.
I try to fetch some data from my mariaDB with the following condition.

```
  $contentList = $this->get();
        foreach($contentList as $content){
            $this->product()->where('id', '=', $content->content_product_id)->ddRawSql();
        }
```

But the query I get is:

```
 select * from `radio_content_products` where `radio_content_products`.`id` is null and `id` = 3
```

The value of the `id` is correct, but by big question is: Why there is this `` `radio_content_products`.`id` is null `` in my condition?

Comment: What happen if you remove the `where` clause ?

Comment: If i remove my where clause the query is: `select * from 'radio_content_products' where 'radio_content_products'.'id' is null `
So the `.... is null` clause stays.

Answer (score 0):

this line `$this->product()`, is a relationship query where it pass the main model id to its related model, can be translated to this query

```
select * from `radio_content_products` where `radio_content_products`.`id` is null
```

which appears to be that your `$this` model is passing null ID for whatever reason you are doing (maybe the way you are dumping the query does not have valid `$this` model)

the second line `->where('id', '=', $content->content_product_id)` is equal to this

```
and `id` = 3
```

Also, I dont think that loop would even work, you should just transform whatever that `$this->get()` is, into a collection, then pluck the `content_product_id` and use `whereIn` in your query.

e.i.

```
$this->product()
    ->whereIn('id', collect( $this->get() )->pluck('content_product_id') )
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wondering about adding a `where` clause to the relationship. You can just write the next single line of code as illustrated also in [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

```
$products = \App\Models\User::first()->products;
```

The previous code gets all the products of the first user using the `products` relationship method that must be defined in the `User.php` model such as:

```
// \App\Models\User.php

public function products(): HasMany
{
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

As Laravel illustrated in the previous link, Laravel will assume that the `products` table contains `user_id` that will match the value in the `id` column of the `users` table.

### Update 1.0

You can add a `where` clause also to the `product` relationship method such as the next sample of code:

```
$specificProducts = \App\Models\User::first()
    ->products
    ->where('price', '>', 1000);
```